# Test Class for Approval Process - Problem with ProcessInstanceWorkItem

Tags: apex, unit-test, approval-process

I'm starting with code and test classes. I have a class that reject an approval process for an account. I start this class by a process builder.

This is the code:

```
public class ALI_RechazoPAprobacion_Expediente {
    @InvocableMethod
    public static void RechazarExpediente(List<Id> ExpId){
        try{        
            list<Account> AccList = [SELECT id FROM account WHERE id in:ExpId];
            Approval.ProcessWorkitemRequest[] prWkItems = New Approval.ProcessWorkItemRequest[]{};

            //Comprueba que el expediente está bloqueado
            //if (Approval.isLocked(AccList[0].Id) == true){

                //Reject the record
                ProcessInstance[] pi = [Select ID, Status, TargetObject.Name, (SELECT Id, ActorId, ProcessInstanceId FROM Workitems),
                    (SELECT Id, StepStatus, Comments FROM Steps) From ProcessInstance 
                    Where TargetObjectID IN :AccList AND Status = 'Pending'];

                for(ProcessInstance instance : pi){

                    for(ProcessInstanceWorkItem workItem : instance.WorkItems){

                        Approval.ProcessWorkitemRequest prWkItem = new Approval.ProcessWorkitemRequest();                   
                        prWkItem.setWorkItemID(workItem.id);
                        prWkItem.setComments('Proceso de aprobación cancelado por superar el límite de tiempo sin contestación');
                        prWkItem.setAction('Reject');
                        prWkItems.add(prWkItem);                     
                    }
                }  

                if(!prWkItems.isEmpty()){
                    Approval.ProcessResult[] appResult = Approval.process(prWkItems);
                }
            //}    
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            System.debug('ERROR EXCEPTION' + ex);           
        }
    }
}
```

---

The class works perfectly, but I'm having some troubles to make its test class.

This is the code

```
/*@isTest static void ExpedienteCompleto(){
        Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name='Territorial']; 

        //Crea el usuario y lo inserta
        User user1 = new User(Alias = 'standt', Email='standarduser@testorg.com', 
                              EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8', LastName='Testing', 
                              LanguageLocaleKey='en_US', 
                              LocaleSidKey='en_US', ProfileId = p.Id, 
                              TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles', 
                              UserName='standarduser@aliseda.com');
        insert user1;
        if(user1 != null){
            System.debug('Usuario insertado: '+ user1.LastName);
        }
        //Crea la cuenta y la inserta
        Account acc = new Account(Name='Test1 PA', 
                                  Director_Territorial__c=user1.Id);
        Insert acc;
        if(acc != null){
            System.debug('Cuenta insertada: '+ acc.Name);
        }

        //Añade el Id de la cuenta a una lista de Ids que se pasan al método
        List<Id> ListAcc = new List<Id>();
        ListAcc.add(acc.Id);

        // Create an approval request for the account
        Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest req1 = new Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest();
        req1.setComments('Submitting request for approval.');
        req1.setObjectId(acc.id);
        req1.setNextApproverIds(ListAcc);

        // Submit on behalf of a specific submitter
        req1.setSubmitterId(user1.Id); 

        // Submit the record to specific process and skip the criteria evaluation
        req1.setProcessDefinitionNameOrId('Asignacion_Ingenieria');
        req1.setSkipEntryCriteria(true);    

        ALI_RechazoPAprobacion_Expediente.RechazarExpediente(listAcc);
    }
```

---

I'm able to cover the 50% of the class:

[image]

My test code can't access to the processInstanceWorkItem. I'm trying with some examples that I found here but I am failing.

Can anyone give me a clue or something? because i'm really stuck.